# How to get string from deeply nested JSON dictionary using SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift

Thanks in advance!

How would I go about accessing the price $50,000 as a string from this JSON file that looks like this? I have been trying with SwiftyJSON

```
{ "Car": { "FourWheel": { "TwoDoor": { "Red": { "Stripes": { "Price": "$50,000" } } } } } }
```

If you think I should change the layout of the JSON file to make it easier, let me know. I've been trying to get the string containing the price  for days!

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
func parseData(data: AnyObject?) -> String? {
    if data == nil {
        return nil
    }
    let json = JSON(data!)

    if let _price = json["Car"]["FourWheel"]["TwoDoor"]["Red"]["Stripes"]["Price"].string {
        return _price
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still returning nil